# How do I get my blog on Feed Burner?

Tags: feeds

I'm trying to get my blog onto Google Feed Burner. I've read all about this, but there doesn't seem to be a clear answer. I just get this error.

> Received HTTP error code 400 while fetching source feed.

I then validate my blog feed through feedvalidator.org. It says it's validated, but it shows the following message.

> This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.
> line 38, column 0: Missing atom:link with rel="self" [help]

The help link seems useless, and I don't think this "recommendation" from the feed validator is my issue. Nonetheless, I've installed
http://drupal.org/project/views_rss  as well as http://drupal.org/project/feedburner.

I've tried burning my feed through the Feed Burner module, but nothing seems to be validated. It looks like there's a lot of Drupal folks having similar problems without a clear answer/tutorial.

Here's what I have:

1. Drupal6 site. A blog page with numerous blog posts, each with a teaser. URL example.com/blog
2. What appears like a valid RSS feed when I type in example.com/blog/feed. This spits out some text which looks like.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <rss version="2.0" xml:base="https://example.com"    
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
   <channel>
   <title>Example blogs</title>
   <link>https://example.com/blog</link>
   <description></description>
   <language>en</language>
   <item>
   ```
3. I've set up a google Feed Burner account.
4. I installed the RSS Views and the Feed Burner modules.

I don't know what else to do. I keep getting that awful error.

Hopefully someone out there can help.

Answer (score 0):

This one is ugly on google's part. My site is https, and feedburner doesn't support SSL... I figured that out the hard way.  I didn't want to muck around with my SSL settings given that it's a wildcard cert, so I figured out a painless workaround. 
1. Subscribe to your blog feed through Google reader.
2. Create a bundle folder with your blog feed.
3. Grab the bundle URL (not https, which is the workaround)
4. Paste it into feedburner.

Done, google accepts that, and gives you a branded feedburner url.

I'm sure there's a better approach, but this was an easy workaround for those with https sites.